# Exclude specific cells from being included in a formula's calculation, even if said cells are referenced by the formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I maintain a spreadsheet for a virtual racing competition. Within it, I have to log the times of each racer and how many points they have earned. I do so by importing a .csv file for each race (the import takes place on a secondary document, which is linked to the main one via DGET if that matters).

[Screenshot of a spreadsheet page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWQUz.png)

In Column G, I calculate the total time for all races, via basic addition: `=C5+E5`, `=C6+E6` etc.

But sometimes racers crash, which automatically replaces their time (HH:MM:SS.MsMs) in the .csv file, with a percentage value (%) denoting how far they got when they crashed. This causes the addition formula to spit out a wildly inaccurate result, as the software does its best to add a time value and a percentage value which represent a distance together.

**Can I write a formula which only adds together the cells which have the proper time format?**

So, for example, I set X99, Y99, and Z99, to be added together, but if Y99 contains a percentage value, it is excluded from the calculation, and the final output is the value of X99+Z99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
= IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(X99),"%"),0,X99)
+ IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(Y99),"%"),0,Y99)
+ IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(Z99),"%"),0,Z99)
```

It turns the number into a text string, then searches for a "%" in the string; if it finds one it adds 0, otherwise adds the time value.

**Documentation:**

- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)